# Why is my c# code not working?

Tags: c#

I have made a console program in c# that is like a to-do task manager.
But it does not work when a certain code is reached:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace To_Do_List
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"C:\ToDoTask.txt";
        Console.WriteLine("To-do program");
        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.ReadLine() == "exit")
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            if (Console.ReadLine() == "add")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please write your task and then press enter");
                string task = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Task added");
                try
                {
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
                    sw.WriteLine(task);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: could not write task to file");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }

            if (Console.ReadLine() == "show")
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tasks:");
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
                    if (sr.ReadToEnd() != "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No tasks left");
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: could not read tasks file");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }

            if (Console.ReadLine() == "help")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Write 'add' to add a new task");
                Console.WriteLine("Write 'show' to see current tasks");
                Console.WriteLine("Write 'exit' to exit program");
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I am new programming and I can't find the error.
When I write add, show or exit, or help nothing happens.
Thanks.

Comment: Where is the error occurring? What kind of error is it? The more specific your question is, the better.

Comment: Because your code has multiple problems, and you didn't specify exactly what the problem is, you now end up with multiple answers, all addressing different problems with your code.

Comment: I did not know were was the error occuring, that is the question.  
And all the answers helped me.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz 's point is that you didn't state what the problem was, you just said "it isn't working."

Comment: @CesarTorres, it's questions like this that drive everyone crazy.. if you write code, then you should also know how to debug the code.. we are not here to test , debug, nor teach  you how to code.. this will definitely get some major downvotes.. hopefully next time you will do your do diligence prior to coming back and posting another question when you should learn how to use the debugger..

Answer (score 5):

One problem is that you keep calling `Console.ReadLine()` for every comparison. That means you're checking *a new input* from the user every time.

Instead, you need to call `Console.ReadLine()` just once, store the result in a variable, and then compare that against all of the possible matches. Also, using a `switch` statement will make your code simpler.

```
while (true)
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (input)
    {
        case "exit":
            Environment.Exit(0);
            break;

        case "add":
            // ...
            break;

        // ...

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new StreamWriter in each iteration of the while loop, effectively writing over any previous data that was in the file. Create the writer outside the loop and close it outside as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problems pointed out above, you need to put your StreamWriters and StreamReaders inside of "using" blocks. To begin with, since you're never calling Flush(), Close(), or Dispose() you'll never actually write anything to the file. Also, once you open the StreamReader or StreamWriter once you'll have a race condition because you have no way of knowing when the file will be closed, so if you call "add" on two consecutive iterations (for example) you'll get an exception saying that the file is in use by a different process.

You also don't want to hardcode the file location or put the file in C:\ - you want to put it in a specific folder, not in the root of the C:\ drive.